# Direct Visual Studio F1 keypress to an internal help server for components I have authored

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2013, sandcastle, xml-comments

I have my code documented with XML comments and am learning how to use SandCastle to generate html API help documentation.  I'm going to publish that html documentation to an internal website.

How can I register this site with visual studio, or my assembly so that Visual Studio will go to it when a user presses F1 in the context of one of my assembly's identifiers to go to the documentation I've published?

Answer (score 1):

You need to ensure you are building the MS Help Viewer (mshc) format with Sandcastle. Once you have done this, a manifest is created (.msha) in the output directory. After the build it will start the wizard to add the content to *your* help viewer, but to add the documentation to Visual Studio on other machines, you must manually add the content.

Either use the Visual Studio hotkey chord `Ctrl+F1, M` or just open the Help viewer with F1 and choose the Manage Content icon at the top. Then you just need to point it to your .msha file. I have been able to do this from a network share, but I imagine it would work fine from a website, perhaps adding `file://` to the beginning of the URL.

It is possible to automate this deployment, but may be overkill for your use case. Nevertheless, more info on that can be found [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh492077.aspx).